# refcount() or autoConnect() for fragments

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a fragment in which I perform an API request. This fragment can go to backstack as a result of a fragment replace and later come back.
That time since only the view is re-created, I dont want to re-execute the Api call. 
For that what I did is, I made my Api call in repository `multicasted` as shown below

```
        public Flowable<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
                return mRemoteRepository.getMovies()
                        .flatMap(movieResponse -> Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
                            List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (MovieResponse.Result result : movieResponse.results) {
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setName(result.title);
                                movies.add(movie);
                            }
                            return movies;
                        })).replay().refCount();
            }
```

My intention was to replay the old result to the new subscribers. So that after fragment view re-creation if I again get a call to the 
same Api request it would replay the old response. 
But here what I could see is it re-executes each time whenever I come back from the backstack.

I think this is because the previous `getMovies()` would have finished emitting when the Api call completed.
Is this correct? `replay().refcount()` will perform replay only during an on-going emission and if new subscribers  are coming in ?

Then I tried `replay().autoConnect()` and it worked as expected. It does not duplicate the API request
when fragment come back from backstack. So what I can understand is `autoconnect()` will keep 
the observable active even if `getMovies()` done with the Api call.
Is it correct? But will it cause any memory leak or outofmemory issue by using it in my case?
Is it safe to use `autoConnect` for my api calls? how can I terminate the `autoconnect` Observable
when my fragment itself is removed?

Answer (score 0):

To terminate a stream with `autoConnect()`, use a `takeUntil()` before the `autoConnect()` and trigger an event when you need to "dispose" the stream.

```
stream().takeUntil(detachEvent())
        .onTerminateDetach()
        .replay().autoConnect()
        .onTerminateDetach()
```

Comment: So I can just create a `Completable` and pass it as the `takeUntil` param , just `complete()` it on the fragment destroy event?